Unable to install package grpc-dev
My ubuntu is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
    $ sudo apt install grpc-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grpc-dev

I have also run
 sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config cmake
sudo apt-get install -y protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev
sudo apt install grpc-dev
sudo apt-get install -y git cmake build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config

What is wrong? How to install successfully?

Did you perhaps mean libgrpc-dev ?

After seeing your comment I ran sudo apt install  libgrpc-dev and able to get rid of one error which lead me to want to install grpc. sudo apt install  libgrpc-dev works. Thanks!
Can you answer this, so that I can accept it?
